# Access .tar.gz files from Jenkins UI

Tags: jenkins

I have recently moved some projects from TeamCity to Jenkins. One very nice feature of TC was the ability to open and explore the contents of a .tar.gz build artifact w/out having to download the full .tar.gz file. If there was a 150 MB .tar.gz and you wanted only one file from that distribution, you only had to download that.

Is an interaction with the Jenkins service possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. :-) But I'm now familiar with the plug-ins enough to know that it is probably possible from there... if someone is willing to write it.